# Suppress database change message in SQLCMD.exe

Tags: sql-server, scripting, sqlcmd

I am writing a script generation script.
The script is generating list of DDL statments.

The `util_generator.sql` generation starts with database connection:

```
USE [TARGET_DATABASE]
GO
...
Many queries
Followed by print statements
...
```

Since this is a very long script, with unknown length.
We use `SQLCMD.exe`

```
sqlcmd -s sa\password -i util_generator.sql -r0 -o util_1.sql
```

The generated scripts `util_1.sql` looks something like this:

```
Changed database context to 'TARGET_DATABASE'.
CREATE TABLE ...
CREATE INDEX ...
CREATE VIEW ...
```

The problem is the generated script `util_1.sql` fails on unknown command `Changed database context to 'TARGET_DATABASE'.`

I need assistance to suppress `Changed database context to 'TARGET_DATABASE'.` message from `SQLCMD.exe`

Using SSMS `util_generator.sql` works good not producing any `Changed database context to 'TARGET_DATABASE'.` message.

But we cannot run `util_generator.sql` on SSMS from CLI for unknown length output scripts.

Please asvise how to suppress `Changed database context to 'TARGET_DATABASE'.` statement in SQLCMD.exe

Comment: Does your script connect to multiple databases during execution or only one database?  If you only run the script against a single database, you could include the `-d` switch to force `sqlcmd` to connect to that database.

Comment: We always use the same target database. I will test now with `-d` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following comment from Scott Hodgin.

The solution is to remove `USE [TARGET_DATABASE]` from `util_generator.sql` script.

And assign the target database via `SQLCMD.exe` using `-d` option.

The expected `SQLCMD.exe` is:

```
sqlcmd -s sa\password -i util_generator.sql -r0 -o util_1.sql -d TARGET_DATABASE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress (error) messages with a severity level lower than 10. Add -m10 as  startup option.

to the best of my knowledge, there is no direct way for SQLCMD to suppress that particular message. But perhaps suppressing info-type messages (as per above) will cut it?

Or, of course, use the -d switch as suggested by Dudi.